# Scaled down image is blurry after printing

Tags: .net, vb.net, image

I am having an issue where I am scaling down an image and then try to print said image.

However when printed, the image gets blurry. Here is the code I am using to resize the image and print.

```
Private Sub printDocument2_PrintPage(ByVal sender As System.Object,
   ByVal e As System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs) Handles _
   printDocument2.PrintPage
    DriverSheetImage2 = New Bitmap(DriverSheetImage, DriverSheetImage.Width * 0.85, DriverSheetImage.Height * 0.85)
    e.Graphics.InterpolationMode = Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor
    e.Graphics.PixelOffsetMode = Drawing2D.PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(DriverSheetImage2, 0, 0)
End Sub
```

Am I missing a graphics property to smooth things out or resize this in a way that won't cause a blurry image?

Comment: Don't put it in a bitmap.  Call the DrawImage method with the parameters that accept a destination rectangle.

Comment: Thank you that was exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the comment suggested ended up using DrawImage method with a new rectangle so the end code looked like this

```
e.Graphics.DrawImage(DriverSheetImage, New Rectangle(0, 0, DriverSheetImage.Width * 0.85, DriverSheetImage.Height * 0.85))
```